# "anonymous type projection initializer should be simple name or member access expression" with Html.ActionLink

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, lambda

My action link helper is giving the error:

"anonymous type projection initializer should be simple name or member access expression"

Here's the link within my Partial View:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Save", "ClientInformationEdit",new {id = Model.person.LastName}) %>
```

My "ClientInformationEdit" does exist in my Controller.  I've checked that by RC on ActionResult->Go to View which links to the right view but Intellisense is not picking it up.  My model is linking correctly.  I've tried a Lambda expression "id => id.Model.." which doesn't work but, I see from other posts, that this is the problem.

I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: is there a lambda? your sample doesn't have one.

Comment: I know this isn't right but this is it <%= Html.ActionLink("Save","ClientInformationEdit", new lastname => lastname.Model.person.LastName)%>  When I mouse over it I get the message "Expression expected".

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a lambda when creating an anonymous object. Just use an assignment how you have it in your sample.

Comment: But my sample isn't working.  What I want is to be able to use an ActionLink in my partial view but the runtime error in my post's title happens when the partial view tries to render.  I mentioned lambda because I'm trying to eliminate and figure out why I'm getting this error.  It seems my Html.Textbox isn't right either <% Html.TextBox("txtSearchStatus", new {lastname = Model.person.LastName})%>  .  Using regualr HTML 'input' works but no Html.Helpers.